# use of deleted functions in c++

Tags: c++, eclipse

Here is a class I've created:

```
class A{  
private:  
    // some private data members:  
    // 2 const integers  
    // 2 integers  
    // 2 const strings  
public:  
    // C'tor  
    // D'tor  
void f(const A&);  
}
```

In the constructing of every object of this class there are no (explicit) dynamic allocations, only "primitive" types assignments.
(by no explicit dynamic allocations i mean other than how string class handles memory).

when i try this:

```
void f(const A& item){  
    // do some thing  
*this = item;  
    // do other stuff  
}
```

i get the following error:
"use of deleted function 'A& A::operator=(const A&)' "

now i know that the compiler is supposed to provide me a default assignment operator,
and my question is: why the compiler refers to it's default assignment operator as a deleted function? and how do i fix this without assigning all the data member functions manually?

Thanks a lot!
Gal

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Because you have `const` members.  They cannot be assigned to, so the compiler cannot supply an assignment operator.

Comment: **12.8/23 [class.copy]** *A defaulted copy/move assignment operator for class X is defined as deleted if X has: [...] a non-static data member of const non-class type (or array thereof).* See the same paragraph for other cases.

Comment: @Gal B.  Unlike you, I feel that the C++ standard people and compiler vendors are stupid on this point, rather than you. The diagnostic is unhelpful and misleading, and the term "deleted function" in the standard is nonsensical.  If the function exists, it isn't deleted. Does your operating system ever tell you, you cannot open that file, it is deleted? No, it says "file not found". The function is in fact suppressed. Programmers do not want to know about a function which is somehow there, but cannot be used; we want a diagnostic about the root cause of why we cannot do something.

Comment: @kaz I totally agree with you on this one. maybe its because I'm a beginner in c++ but sometimes I find the compiler's errors and warnings hard to understand, and this case is not the only example. Anyway thanks for all the help guys! :)